# Hey guys, i'm trying to make a karaoke scoring system based on pitch and rhythm

Tags: python, numpy, audio, signal-processing, librosa

```
import librosa
import numpy as np

#load the karaoke audio file
y, sr = librosa.load('karaoke_performance.wav')

#pitch contour
arr = librosa.core.pitch.yin(y,fmin=librosa.note_to_hz('C2'),fmax=librosa.note_to_hz("C7"),sr=sr)

#load reference audio file
ref_y, ref_sr = librosa.load('song_reference.wav')

#reference pitch contour 
arr2 = librosa.core.pitch.yin(ref_y,fmin=librosa.note_to_hz('C2'),fmax=librosa.note_to_hz("C7"),sr=ref_sr)

if arr.size > arr2.size:
    newarr = np.pad(arr2, (0,len(arr)-len(arr2)))
    mse = np.mean(np.subtract(newarr,arr2))**2
elif arr2.size > arr.size: 
    newarr = np.pad(arr, (0,len(arr2)-len(arr)))
    mse = np.mean(np.subtract(arr2,newarr))**2
else:
    mse = np.mean(np.subtract(arr,arr2))**2

#tempo, beat frames
tempo, beat_frames = librosa.beat.beat_track(y, sr)

#reference
ref_tempo, ref_beat_frames = librosa.beat.beat_track(ref_y, ref_sr)

#deviation
rhythm_deviation = np.mean(np.abs(beat_frames - ref_beat_frames))

#scoring
pitch_score = 100 - (mse * 100)
rhythm_score = 100 - (rhythm_deviation * 100)
normalized_final_score = (pitch_score + rhythm_score) / 2

print("Pitch Score:", pitch_score)
print("Rhythm Score:", rhythm_score)
print("Final Score:", normalized_final_score)
```

My method is to break down the audio files into their individual samples (22050hz sample rate), calculate the fundamental frequency for each sample, and then subtract these to get the pitch deviation and with that calculate the pitch variance. I'm also trying to calculate the rhythm score based on the deviation of beat frames of the performance and the original song. Unfortunately, neither of these methods have produced usable results as of yet, with testing with my own voice (i am a choir singer :D) showing an average of -76000 points. Where am I messing up?

At first, i had issues with the 2 numpy arrays of the audio file samples not being the same shape, so i padded the smaller one. Now, the scores are impossibly low and i'm trying to find another method of scoring/detecting pitches.

Comment: Are your two audio tracks aligned?

Comment: You should make a visualization of the system to understand what is going on. Plot the input STFT, reference STFT, detected pitch, reference pitch, beat frames etc. And the deviations over time.

Comment: I propose doing just pitch scoring. Make sure this is ok, learn something along the way (analysis Jon suggest is very good idea), then move on to rhythm.